# How to configure nuxt.config to insert css files before js files?

Tags: css, nuxt.js

I've got `extractCSS: true` configuration in my nuxt.config file which splits all css files in order: first loading js then css files.
From what I was reading in best practices: it is recommended to preload css files first.
In my case NUXT imports js chunks first, then related css.
How to configure nuxt.config to insert css files before js files?
reference:https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extractcss

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._.nuxt_A.js" as="script" />
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/_nuxt/app~._.nuxt_A.css"
  as="style"
/>
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/_nuxt/app~._assets_scss_main.scss~c.css"
  as="style"
/>
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._c.css" as="style" />
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/_nuxt/2.js" />
<link
  rel="prefetch stylesheet"
  href="/_nuxt/3.css"
/>
```